# Pass parameter to animate callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery snippet and I'm trying to pass a parameter to the function of animate method but can't get it right.

```
function move() {

    var points = [13, 8, 5];

    for(var pointIdx=0; pointIdx < points.length-1; pointIdx++) {
        ..
        ..

        // animate move.        
        $('#my_id', gameWindow.document).animate({ left: "50px" ,top:  "50px" }, 1500, 'linear', 
            function(pointIdx) {
                console.log("Animation: Iteration=" + pointIdx); // pointIdx is undefined at this point, why?
               ...
               ...
            }
        )
    }
}
```

How to do it right?

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need pointIdx parameter in the animate function. try removing it. Also, you are missing a quote in '#my_id, gameWindow.document. It should be '#my_id, gameWindow.document'

Comment: You are right, but it should be:  $('#my_id', gameWindow.document).animate(....)

Comment: so how can I pass parameter into its complete callback ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pointIdx` is undefined because the complete callback for jQuery's animation does not have any parameters available to use.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> **complete**
>   Type: Function()
>   A function to call once the animation is complete.

So when you include the parameter `pointIdx` in the animate function complete callback like this

```
function(pointIdx) {
```

you are **overwriting** the variable `pointIdx`. Because JavaScript uses a stack of lexical variable environments, `pointIdx` is pushed on to the stack with the value passed in from the complete callback. This value is `undefined`, and when you try to read the value of the variable `pointIdx` inside of the execution context of the complete callback, it gets the top most value of the stack, which is `undefined`. This is why `pointIdx` is undefined here.

In order to store the value of `pointIdx` inside of this callback you need to remove it from the parameters, and also you need to close over it with an IIFE.

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/w528kfp3/)***

```
for(var pointIdx=0; pointIdx < points.length; pointIdx++) {
    ..
    ..

    // animate move.        
    //close over pointIdx
    (function(pointIdx){
    //now the execution context is inside of the anonymous function
    //and the value of pointIdx in the loop is stored in
    //variable pointIdx (same name for consistency) is at the top of that variable environment
    $('#my_id', gameWindow.document).animate({ left: "50px" ,top:  "50px" }, 1500, 'linear', 
        function() {
            console.log("Animation: Iteration=" + pointIdx); // pointIdx will now contain the iteration value from the for loop
           ...
           ...
        }
    )
    })(pointIdx);
}
```

Comment: It's a nice idea, but it doesn't seem to work!  because the animation run in a delay of 1500 millis the for loops ends before it even does the first animation. so eventually when it executes the animation 3 times - the 'pointIdx' value equals 3 in all iterations instead 1,2,3.

Comment: I could have done the same thing without the enclosing function just calling directly 'pointIdx'.

Comment: @Shvalb - No, it is not the same thing because the function *closes* over the value at the time of execution. So when it executes the animation it will still be 1,2,3. Without it, that is when you get 3 all 3 times.

Comment: sorry, it's working perfectly as expected!! don't know why it didn't work for me at the first time!!

Comment: @Shvalb - There was a slight typo in one of the variable names in my prior edit where `pointIdx` was accidentally misspelled `pointIx` in the IIFE parameter name. That was probably the reason :)

Comment: Thank you very much - you're my today's hero :-)

Comment: Note: to view the actual moving the div the Fiddle Demo should be updated to:  
     <div style='position:absolute' id="my_id">div</div>

Answer (score 2):

The problem is timing - the animation callback happens after 1500 ms, but your for loop completes almost instantly. You need to rewrite it like this:

```
var points = [13, 8, 5];
var pointIdx = 0;

function animateForPointIndex(index) {
    $('#my_id').animate({
        left: "50px",
        top: "50px"
    }, 1500, 'linear', function () {
        pointIdx++;
        if (pointIdx < points.length) {
            console.log("Animation: Iteration=" + pointIdx);
            // do what you need to here 
            animateForPointIndex(pointIdx);
        }
    });
}
animateForPointIndex(0);
```

The animate function is called recursively after each completion, only if the point index is less than the length of the points array.

Comment: it's a nice solution for this simple case, but I need the 'for' loop to make some calculations before running the animation.

Comment: You effectively have a for loop - where my comment "do what you need to here" is, you can do the same calculations because pointIdx is iterated.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I advice you to take a look at Travis J's answer - it's cleaner solution (recursions in code is something I rather avoid) and great technique to keep state between events.